# runnable with countdown

Tags: java, android, runnable, android-handler

I am trying to use a `runnable` to count down from 30s to 0, then run a method, then restart. I cannot seem to get this working right. Seems like a very convoluted solution for a simple task...

**`tvHeatCD`** is a `TextView` that should update every sec to show "5s" if 5 seconds remain etc
**`reduceHeat()`** is the method that should run every 30 seconds (matching conditions shown)
**`stopHeatTimer()`** is just calling `handler.removeCallbacks(..)` and `heatTimerRunning = false`

```
 public void checkHeatTimer() {
    RealmResults<Heat> heatList = realm.where(Heat.class).equalTo("theheat","theheat").findAll();
    ht = heatList.get(0);

    if(ht.getHeat() !=0) {
        if(!heatTimerRunning) {
                final int[] countdown = {30};
                tvHeatCD.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                heatRunnable = new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        heatTimerRunning = true;
                        if (!realm.isClosed()) {
                            countdown[0]--;
                            if(countdown[0] == 0) {
                                if (ht.getHeat() != 0) {
                                    Crashlytics.setInt("heat", ht.getHeat());
                                    reduceHeat("normal",20);
                                    stopHeatTimer();
                                    checkHeatTimer();
                                } else {
                                    Crashlytics.setInt("heat", 0);
                                    tvHeatCD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    stopHeatTimer();
                                }
                            }
                            tvHeatCD.setText(countdown[0] + "s");

                            heatHandler.postDelayed(heatRunnable, 1000);
                        } else if (realm.isClosed()) {
                            recreate();
                        }

                    }
                };
                heatHandler.postDelayed(heatRunnable, 30000);
            }


    } else {
        tvHeatCD.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

Appreciate any help...thank you!

Comment: Hey there, please explain what exactly is not working as intended, is it that the runnable is not being called?

Comment: @LucasDeMoraisCabrales it seems this version will not start for 30s in the beginning, but after that it seems fine. Having a time trying to understand this, thanks

Comment: You could also check out `CountDownTimer`, it might suit your needs the most. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer